# Accessible semantic jQuery tabs plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

Just a quick question to see if anyone knows of any jquery tabs plugins that run based on a similar structure to:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div>
        <h4>Tab one</h4>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h4>Tab two</h4>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where the plugin grabs the title of the tabs from the h4s? I can only seem to find plugins that use the structure:

```
<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Tab 1 content</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Tab 2 content</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>Tab 3 content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I assume the only other way to use these plugins would be to grab the titles, remove them, add them into a list at the top of the html and then run the plugin based on that? I just ask as I am quite new to jQuery so I'm not sure how I would go about it and just wondered if there was a plugin already in existence that anyone knew of.

If not, not to worry, I'll have to get busy with the docs and give it a go!

Cheers

Comment: No, I haven't, but good luck with writing your own.  It's a worthy goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to put something together to get the html to the correct structure to use jQuery UI tabs on - Hopefully someone can learn something from this!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.fn.reverse = [].reverse; //Set the reverse function
    $('#tabs div h4').reverse().prependTo('#tabs'); //Grab the headings and reverse them, then prepend to outer div
    $('#tabs h4').wrap('<li></li>'); //wrap each heading in an li
    $('#tabs > li').wrapAll('<ul class="tabheadings"></ul>'); //wrap all li's in ul
    $('#tabs ul li h4').each(function(){
      $(this).replaceWith('<a>' + $(this).text() + '</a>'); //for each heading replace with an anchor but keep innards
   });
    $('#tabs div.in_content_box').each(function(i){
       $( this ).attr('id', 'tabs-' + (i+1)); //for each div add an id with an incremental number
    });
    $('#tabs ul li a').each(function(i){
        $( this ).attr('href', '#tabs-' + (i+1)); //match the href on the anchor with the id above
     });



});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Accessible Tabs](http://blog.ginader.de/archives/2009/02/07/jQuery-Accessible-Tabs-How-to-make-tabs-REALLY-accessible.php) is almost there, except the header sits outside of the target div.